# why condition statement didn't work properly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, conditional-statements

so im making a game with pathfinding algorithm. with some npc objects. the problem is when I use multiple npc, the condition that I marked is not working properly, but when I only use 1 npc, the condition runs well. Anyone can help me out? Thank You

i'm testing my code with Debug.Log. When the remainingDistance is smaller than stoppingDistance the program will print "R" in console. Everything was working perfectly when i use only one object npc. But when i use multiple npc, the condition isn't work properly. i'm saying that because program didn't print "R", program print "not" instead. it means the remainingDistance is bigger than stoppingDistance, in fact i'm checking the remainingDistance value, and the value is smaller than stoppingDistance.

```
if (HaveReachedDestination ()) 
{
    if (npc.myNavMeshAgent.drawGizmos) 
    {
        Debug.Log ("reach");
    }
    if ((nextWayPoint + 1) == npc.waypoints.Length)
    {
        nextWayPoint = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        nextWayPoint = (nextWayPoint + 1) % npc.waypoints.Length;
        if (npc.myNavMeshAgent.drawGizmos) 
        {
            Debug.Log ("waypoint plus 1");
        }
    }
}

private bool HaveReachedDestination()
{
    if (npc.myNavMeshAgent.drawGizmos) 
    {
        Debug.Log ("remainDistance : " + npc.myNavMeshAgent.remainingDistance.ToString());
        Debug.Log ("stoppingDistance : " + npc.myNavMeshAgent.stoppingDistance.ToString());
    }

    if (npc.myNavMeshAgent.remainingDistance <= npc.myNavMeshAgent.stoppingDistance) 
    {
        if (npc.myNavMeshAgent.drawGizmos) 
        {
            Debug.Log ("R");
        }

        StopWalking ();
        npc.myNavMeshAgent.m_hasPath = false;
        return true;
    } 
    else 
    {
        if (npc.myNavMeshAgent.drawGizmos) 
        {
            Debug.Log ("not");
        }

        KeepWalking ();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Console Screenshot :

Console Screenshot with one NPC :

[image: Console Screenshot with one NPC :]

Console Screenshot With multiple NPC

[image: Console Screenshot With multiple NPC]

Comment: Your first debug works fine, your second debug has no remainDistance smaller than stoppingDistance.0.8013583 is actually greater than 0.8

Comment: oh yaa, I just realized that. then the problem is that the purpose of the npc changes by itself, because in the code that I wrote, the goal will change when these conditions are met. i've been debuging the code for hours.. and i'm still didnt find where the problem is...

Comment: When you say you have multiple and it doesnt work - what exactly happens, there are a lot of variables in that code that have no explaination eg, its not [mcve] and the snippet you offer is hard to debug out of context

Comment: it cause a weird movement. like rotating in place. here is the full code. that snipet code is in this code : https://pastebin.com/NHtcHJZK .that code referring to this code : https://pastebin.com/iqyKiVa8 and https://pastebin.com/AG5Qyahu

Comment: In your `HaveReachedDestination`, you are checking some global `npc`. Maybe you should supply it as parameter to have it work correctly with multiple npcs?

Comment: @HansKeﬆing can u give me an example about the parameter?

Comment: @irwnsyh `HaveReachedDestination(WhateverTheNpcType npc)`, to have it check whether *this particular* npc has reached its destination. Of course you must supply the correct value when you call this.

Comment: For the record, that problem happen if i'm using multiple NPC's.. in that multiple NPC's, some work fine like it should be and than some will have this problem.

Comment: after doing in-depth research, the result I got was that the condition was not executed because when the remainingdistance value was almost close to the stoppingDistance value, the NPC destination position changed itself, even though in the condition code there was no code to change the destination position. have an opinion?

Comment: see the screenshot in this [link](https://postimg.cc/v4vsqd3P)

Comment: @HansKeﬆing i dont think the problem is in the code. because some npc was work perfect.